# how to allow both Apache and sftp users write in user public folders?

Tags: apache-http-server, sftp, ubuntu-14.04

**Requirements:**

1. sftp users need to be able to maintain their account's websites via sftp. I have created a "sftponly" group for them.
2. Apache (user: www-data) needs to be able to read, write and execute in these users' "www" folders. For instance, Wordpress auto-update feature should work without specifying ftp credentials.

The file structure I follow is like this:

```
/home/<username>/www/<domain.tld>/public
```

I managed to make either requirement work, but not the two alongside.

Here is the process I follow to create a new user at the moment:

```
adduser <username>
usermod -G sftponly <username>
chown root:root /home/<username>
chmod 755 /home/<username>
cd /home/<username>
mkdir www
chown -R <username>:sftponly *
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/<username>/www
chmod -R 770 /home/<username>/www
```

How can I meet both requirements?

System: Ubuntu 14.04, Apache 2.4.7

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the easiest way to meet both requirements would probably be to utilize Access Control Lists:

[ACLs -- Arch-Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists)

Just simply add another group like so:

```
setfacl -mR "g:sftponly:rw" /home/<username>/www
```

If you can't, or do not want to use ACL's I would suggest looking at this documentation:

[SCPOnly](https://github.com/scponly/scponly/wiki)

SCPOnly is a special shell that can work with chroot jails and PAM to more securely allow users remote access.